# Is it possible to use the beginBackgroundTask() API within SwiftUI lifecycle?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, google-cloud-functions

I need to run some code when the app is closed to remove the client from a game. To do this I'm wanting to execute a Google Cloud Function for the server to do the cleanup - the function works, I guess similar [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60664671/12647189) I just do not have enough time, and I'm running a completion handler so it's not like iOS thinks the function is finished straight away.

I have seen multiple questions on this, many of which are rather old and do not include answers for the SwiftUI Lifecycle. I have seen this exact issue and a potential answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60664728/12647189), however I'm not using the Realtime Database, I'm using Firestore so there is no equivalents for the `onDisconnect` methods.

I have seen that you can increase the time you need when the application finishes through `beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler:)`, I just can't find anywhere to state this can be done through SwiftUI Lifecycle, what I have so far:

```
.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willTerminateNotification), perform: { output in
        Backend().removeFromGame(gameCode: otp, playerName: "name", completion: { res, error in
            if error != nil{
                print(error)
            }
        })
    })
```

The function called is as follows:

```
 func removeFromGame(gameCode: String, playerName: String, completion: @escaping (Bool?, Error?) -> Void){
    Functions.functions().httpsCallable("removeFromGame").call(["gameCode": gameCode, "playerName": playerName]){ result, error in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            if error.domain == FunctionsErrorDomain{
                _ = FunctionsErrorCode(rawValue: error.code)
                let errorDesc = error.localizedDescription
                _ = error.userInfo[FunctionsErrorDetailsKey]
                print(errorDesc)
            }
        }else{
            print("Removed successfully")
        }
    }
}
```

I have seen in [this Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/extending_your_app_s_background_execution_time) how to use the API:

```
    func sendDataToServer( data : NSData ) {
       // Perform the task on a background queue.
       DispatchQueue.global().async {
       // Request the task assertion and save the ID.
      self.backgroundTaskID = UIApplication.shared.
             beginBackgroundTask (withName: "Finish Network Tasks") {
       // End the task if time expires.
     UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(self.backgroundTaskID!)
     self.backgroundTaskID = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
      }
        
      // Send the data synchronously.
      self.sendAppDataToServer( data: data)
        
      // End the task assertion.
      UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(self.backgroundTaskID!)
      self.backgroundTaskID = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
   }
}
```

Just cannot seem to implement it correctly within the new way of getting these system notifications?

Comment: Actually that might be too late to begin background task, system might get luck of time to detect it - you need to think how to start it earlier, maybe on didEnterBackgroundNotification maybe even earlier. Actually answer for the topic question is YES (it does not depend on life-cycle at all), but you have to find moment where to start.

Comment: @Asperi that’s what I was afraid of. I’m not sure how to go about it then as I can/only want to remove the player from said game if and ONLY IF the app is fully closed, I cannot remove them every time they put the app in the background on the off chance it’ll actually lead to them not going back to the app. Is there any other way?

Comment: I'm about background task - not about exact remove operation... you can start fake background operation (say only observed for notification) and inside this operation once catch willTerminate... starting real activity. BackgroundTask is only a frame indicating for system that something going on and needs special attention - you can do in this frame anything.

Comment: @Asperi could you provide an example as a potential answer based off the willTerminate?